# How to stop SWIG from throwing Syntax Errors for type Macros (c++ to python)

Tags: c++, macros, swig, preprocessor

I am pretty new to SWIG (and c++ as well) and am trying to wrap something called p_convolve.hpp from a library called evergreenforest to python (You can check it out here: https://bitbucket.org/orserang/evergreenforest/src/master/). I cannot get very far because SWIG throws a syntax error when it reaches the use of a macro defined elsewhere in the library. I am using c++11, python 2.7, and the latest version of swig.

I have just started, haven't actually tried to wrap and get the type maps in order yet, just wanted to see if it would even compile, and I get a syntax error. The error is on a line that uses what I believe is called a macro that is defined in FLOAT_TYPE.hpp in the utilities for the library. I will post the code for that file below, as well as the line that causes the error. I haven't tried anything yet because I could not find "macro" or "define" in the swig documentation and have no clue what to do. I am also using numpy.i, which I haven't gotten far enough to actually do anything with yet, but it would be appreciated if any solutions meshed well with it as well.

```
//The macro, or at least that's what I think it's called, which is          
//included  in the problem file
#ifndef _FLOAT_TYPE_HPP
#define _FLOAT_TYPE_HPP

  #ifdef FAST_FLOAT
    typedef float FLOAT_TYPE;
  #else
    #ifdef ACCURATE_FLOAT
      typedef long double FLOAT_TYPE;
    #else
      // standard
      typedef double FLOAT_TYPE;
    #endif
  #endif

 #endif
```

The line that causes the problem from p_convolve.hpp:

```
const FLOAT_TYPE tau_denom(1e-9L);
```

The .i file, p_convolve.i:

```
%module p_convolve
%include "std_vector.i"

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "p_convolve.hpp"
#include <array>
#include <set>
#include "naive_convolve.hpp"
#include "fft_convolve.hpp"
#include "../Utility/FLOAT_TYPE.hpp"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%include "p_convolve.hpp"
```

And finally, just to be thorough, what I compile with:

```
swig -python -c++ p_convolve.i
g++ -fpic -c p_convolve_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/home/sean/Desktop/SerangLab/Swig/numpy/numpy/core/include/ -I/home/sean/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/
g++ -shared p_convolve_wrap.o -o _p_convolve.so
```

My expected or hoped for results are for this thing to be able to compile into a module - .it won't be a a good one or useful one until I get the typemaps and such in, but just to be rid of these syntax errors is the current goal. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SWIG doesn't recurse into include files included in the top level file referenced with `%include`, so you need to specifically `%include` other files that you need definitions from.  This is intentional...you don't normally want to generate interfaces for everything in `<stdio.h>` or `<iostream>` just because they are used in your include file.

So you probably need at least:

```
%include "float_type.hpp"
%include "p_convolve.hpp"
```

If you don't want to include in your SWIG interface every thing in `float_type.hpp`, you can at least provide the definitions you do need:

```
typedef double FLOAT_TYPE;
%include "p_convolve.hpp"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I tried it (got the right file path and everything) and still got an error on that line. It turns out that it doesn't like that the variable is declared like `type varName(value)` instead of being declared like `type varName = value`. No obligation since you already answered my main question, but would you happen to know why it dislikes the former way / how to get around it?